# How to set Unit test AppDomain FriendlyName?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, .net-4.0

I use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName` to name a file yet I get `UnitTestAdapter: Running test` as friendly name which leads to `---> System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.`. I have a dedicated test class marked with [TestClass] attribute and [TestMethod] in it. How and where can I set `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName` for UnitTest?

Comment: I'm not sure what's you test or the system under test (SUT) looks like. But I think what you really want is to stub out the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName so when it calls you get a pre-defined friendly name - which you have control over.
You can use an isolotion framework, if not simple hand written stub. I cannot give a definite answer because the question is bit vague.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?